# C# and ClosedXML :: Possible to Open a File as Read Only?

Tags: c#, file, closedxml

I'm writing a C# program that uses ClosedXML as a library.  The code opens an Excel spreadsheet, then reads the contents:

```
using ClosedXML.Excel;

public foo()
{
    var workbook = new XLWorkbook("C:\\Users\\me\\testSpreadsheet.xlsx");
    // read and process the data
}
```

Simple.  I noticed, however, that if I have the spreadsheet file open and then I run the code, the `new XLWorkbook()` command throws an IOException:

```
System.IO.IOException: 'The process cannot access the file 'C:\\Users\\me\\testSpreadsheet.xlsx' because it is being used by another process.
```

That makes sense; both the C# code and Excel can't edit the file at the same time.  But ideally, I'd like the user to be able to have the file open, make edits, save them, and then be able to run the code without having to close the spreadsheet.

For giggles, I tried a `try/catch` solution:

```
using ClosedXML.Excel;

public foo()
{
    try
    {
        var workbook = new XLWorkbook("C:\\Users\\me\\testSpreadsheet.xlsx");
        // read and process the data
    }
    catch(System.IO.IOException e)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("GAH!!! Excel spreadsheet is open!");
        System.Console.WriteLine(e);
    }
}
```

But this had no effect.  When I run the above code with the spreadsheet open, the `new XLWorkbook()` line throws the exact same error.  And besides, I think the problem is that `new XLWorkbook()` is trying to open the file with RW privledges.

So, any ideas here?  The ClosedXML documentation doesn't mention anything about opening a file as RO.  So maybe ClosedXML was the wrong library?  Any comments/advice is welcome.  Thank you.

Comment: There is `XLWorkbook(Stream stream)` constructor version ... Did you tried to use it with readonly `FileStream` ?

Comment: @Selvin Thanks Selvin.  I had no idea you could do this!  So I would somehow define the Excel worksheet as a RO stream and then pass that into `new XLWorkbook()`?

Comment: `new XLWorkbook(File.OpenRead(path))` or `new XLWorkbook(new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))`  (maybe you should have references to disspose stream) as long as other process open file with `FileShare.Read` flag should works

Comment: @Selvin So the first solution had no effect, but the second solution worked beautifully!  ( `new XLWorkbook(new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))` )  If you write it up as a response, I'll happily credit you with the solution.  THanks!